# Validate my username; wrong credential error message in same window

Tags: javascript, html

I am performing validation using JavaScript. My validation is working properly but I want to show an error upon incorrect input on the same page as shown in the image

The Required Scenario upon Invalid Input
[image]

```js
function validate() {
  var x = new String(document.forms["adminForm"]["adminName"].value);
  if (x != "zzzz")
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="js/adminValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img alt="Image Not Found" src="images/Header1.jpg" style="background-color: #fffffff; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<br>
<br>
<form name="adminForm" action="AdminChoice.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <center>
    <table>
      <th>
        <td> <b>Login</b> </td>
      </th>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Admin User Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="adminName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <center><input type="submit" value="Login"></center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</form>
```

Comment: Why `new String(document.forms["adminForm"]["adminName"].value);` - form field values are always string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another row in your form table to show/hide error message on validation.

Add error message container:

```
<tr><td id="error" class="error hidden">Wrong credentials...</td></tr>
```

Toggle the class 'hidden' of error container on validation

```
var error = document.getElementById('error');
error.classList.toggle('hidden');
```

A working example of your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/poqxa59y/5/

Comment: You can click `<>` and create the snippet here instead of JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A very simple scenario would be to just have an element with the required text feedback and show/hide it depending on whether the validations succeeds or not

This is like a very very simple example and it wont fit for any properly created validation system, but it should get you going for a start :D

```js
function validate() {
  document.getElementById('ValidationFeedbackContainer').style.display = "none"; // hide before validation starts
  var x = new String(document.forms["adminForm"]["adminName"].value);
  if (x != "zzzz") {
    document.getElementById('ValidationFeedbackContainer').style.display = "block"; // show it
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}
document.getElementById('ValidationFeedbackContainer').style.display = "none"; // hide before validation starts
```

```html
<form name="adminForm" action="AdminChoice.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th> <b>Login</b> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Admin User Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adminName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="ValidationFeedbackContainer" style="color:red;display:none;">
      <td>My custom asdasd error message goes in here!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <center><input type="submit" value="Login"></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please bother to test your code. You were missing TD and a working snippet